# Keep dropdown open on hover jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a quick animated drop down. I have it working great when you `mouseover` and `mouseout` on the initial button. I just cant get the HTML div that drops down to "hold" when you're hovered on the dropdown itself. here is a fiddle of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/kAhNd/

here's what I'm doing in the JS:

```
$('.navBarClickOrHover').mouseover(function () {
    var targetDropDown = $(this).attr('targetDropDown');
    var targetDropDownHeight = $('#' + targetDropDown).height();
    $('#' + targetDropDown).animate({
        'height': '200px'
    });
}).mouseout(function () {
    if ($('.dropdownCont').is(':hover') || $('.navBarClickOrHover').is(':hover')) {

    } else {
        var targetDropDown = $(this).attr('targetDropDown');
        var targetDropDownHeight = $('#' + targetDropDown).height();
        $('#' + targetDropDown).animate({
            'height': '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

It works, but the element doesn't stay dropped down when you have your mouse over it. I added in

```
if ($('.dropdownCont').is(':hover') || $('.navBarClickOrHover').is(':hover')) {

    }
```

to try to make it do nothing when you're hovered over '.dropdownCont'.

Having a hard time explaining it. I'm sorry, I hope I make sense. Any help would be awesome! here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kAhNd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code transformed http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/kAhNd/3/

```
var button = $('.navBarClickOrHover');
var isItOverTheDropdown = false;
var showDropDown = function() {
    var targetDropDown = $('#' + button.attr('targetDropDown'));
    var targetDropDownHeight = targetDropDown.height();
    targetDropDown.animate({
        'height': '200px'
    });
    targetDropDown.off("mouseenter").on("mouseenter", function() {
        isItOverTheDropdown = true;
    });
    targetDropDown.off("mouseleave").on("mouseleave", function() {
        isItOverTheDropdown = false;
        hideDropDown();
    });
}
var hideDropDown = function() {
    var targetDropDown = $('#' + button.attr('targetDropDown'));
    var targetDropDownHeight = targetDropDown.height();
    targetDropDown.animate({
        'height': '0px'
    });
}

$('.navBarClickOrHover').mouseover(function () {
    showDropDown();
}).mouseout(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        !isItOverTheDropdown ? hideDropDown : '';
    }, 500);
});
```

I guess that this is what you want to achieve.